# xamarin How to save image source to photo library in android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I wrote the code below to save the image source.

here is my code

```
   public void SavePictureToDisk(string filename, byte[] imageData)
    {
        Java.IO.File storagePath = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures);
        Context context = MainActivity.Instance;
       
        var pictures = storagePath.AbsolutePath;
        
        string name = filename + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff") + ".jpg";

        string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(pictures, name);
        try
        {
            Logger.Instance.Write($"{name}");
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, imageData);
            
            var mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionMediaScannerScanFile);
            mediaScanIntent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(new File(filePath)));
            context.SendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            Logger.Instance.Write(e.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

On emulator and on my gelaxy s 21, the save works fine. However, in previous models of gelaxy s 21, there was a bug that could not be saved. May I know what I did wrong?

It wasn't an issue with permission settings.

Comment: "there was a bug" - what does this mean?  Did you get an exception or error message?  Are the "previous models" where it does not work running a different version of Android?

Comment: When I tested with a device model older than the gelaxy s 21 model, all was not saved. It was saved normally in gelaxy s 21 and emulator.

Comment: `However, in previous models of gelaxy s 21, there was a bug that could not be saved.`   On which phones can the problem be reproduced? Can you tell us the brand and model, as well as the Android version?